# Is it possible to use anonymous types and InternalsVisibleTo?

Tags: c#, dynamic, xamarin, portable-class-library, internalsvisibleto

I am building a `Xamarin.Forms` application. I have two libraries:

- MyProj.ViewModels
- MyProj.DataAccess

My `DataAccess` libary is accessing my `Sqlite` database and returning a `dynamic` object like so:

```
var calls = from customer in conn.Table<Customer>().ToList()
            join call in conn.Table<Calls>().ToList()
            on customer.Id equals call.CustomerId
            group customer by call.CallDate into grouped
            select new { Customers = grouped, CallDate = grouped.Key };
```

I would then like to access the properties of this dynamic object in my `ViewModels` library but due to `dynamic` objects being `internal` I get an exception saying:

> object does not contain a definition for 'x'

I thought about adding the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyProj.ViewModels")]
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to use `anonymous / dynamic` types and the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute to access `dynamic` objects in a different library to the one they were created in?

but this doesn't seem to work.

**PS.**

I have also checked whether my assembly is a strongly named assembly [using this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wriju/2008/07/01/how-to-find-public-key-token-for-a-net-dll-or-assembly/) and I can confirm it isn't a strongly named assembly.

I have also checked that an `Internal TestClass` is visible to my `MyProj.ViewModels` libary which it was, so I can confirm the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute works, it just doesn't work with `dynamic` could this be a portable class library bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return/consume dynamic anonymous type across assembly boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993200/return-consume-dynamic-anonymous-type-across-assembly-boundaries)

Comment: @JamesThorpe The `ExpandoObject` doesn't seem to work with my `Sqlite` query. I am trying to use the query outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39109727/2987066)

Comment: Check beyond the accepted answer on that one, there are alternatives too.  However also make note of this from the accepted answer which I agree with: _"In general, anonymous types should really only be used within the same method in which they are generated. Returning an anonymous type from a method is, in general, going to cause more problems than it solves."_

Comment: Can't you create a Non Anonymous class and use?

Comment: It is [known to work](http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic).  Smells like a Mono-specific issue, its DLR not paying attention to [InternalsVisibleTo] perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant both libraries are .Net PCL libraries, could it be a .Net issue?