# What should be the type parameter for List<T> and .Query<T> for joined table?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I am very new to Xamarin Forms and SQLite. I have the following method that returns a list from two joined tables. My problem is I don't know what is the right type parameter the `List<T>` and `.Query<>` should have to be able to get the values of both `Category` and `Phrase` table. Can anyone enlighten me on this one?

```
public List<?> GetWordsByCategory(int category)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        var words = databaseConnection
                    .Query<?>("Select Category.*, Phrase.* 
                               From Category 
                               Join Phrase on Category.Id = Phrase.CategoryId 
                               Where Category.Id = 1")
                    .ToList();
        return words;    
    }
}
```

I have tried `List<Category>` but would only return the properties of the Category table likewise `List<Phrase>`

Comment: You need to create a new class that has the properties of both combined classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `dynamic` or create a new class.

But I would suggest you to use the SQLite.Net PCL which is a wrapper around SQL and which enables you to query database like EF using linq and lamda than string queries.

You can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106298/is-it-possible-to-return-dynamic-objects-or-dataset-from-a-sqlite-query/39109727#39109727) similar question which should help you.

Comment: Isn't `dynamic` not allowed on actual iOS devices?

Comment: I have used it and never had any issues. Do you have any issues?

Comment: I have had issues before and according to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation) link, iOS hardware is specifically set to not allow dynamic code. Having said that, I think that it does allow some scenarios with `dynamic`s. So maybe it is just something to look out for if a problem does arise. Unfortunately it was a while ago when I had the issue so I cannot remember the situation or the error :|

Comment: iOS has issues with dynamic code generation and not using dynamic data type.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes more sense! Thanks.